# getting error: "Property 'user' does not exist on type 'ArrayBuffer'. in Angular

Tags: angular, properties, arraybuffer

So I want to diplay user information in the Profilecomponent, but whenever I run the server I get the same message two times: Property 'user' does not exist on type 'ArrayBuffer'. I have tried to look it up but so far I havent got any clue what is causing this. Can anyone help?
This is profile.component.ts:

```
  username;
email;

constructor(private auth: AuthService) { }

ngOnInit() {
this.auth.getProfile().subscribe(profile => {
  this.username = profile.user.username;
  this.email = profile.user.email;

  })
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try changing the response as any, in this case,

```
this.auth.getProfile().subscribe((profile:any) => {
  this.username = profile.user.username;
  this.email = profile.user.email;
})
```